# How AWS EB works for each deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a project in EB linked with codePipline from Github, and I have some files inside my project in `.ebextensions` & `.platform` folders

My question is: Does `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` deploy these files each time I deploy a new version to EB or just one time?

How EB  worked behind the sense!?

Answer (score 0):

the `.ebextensions` and `.platform` folders need to be part of your application code. So if you're using the CodePipeline Elastic Beanstalk deployment task, the input artefact needs to have these folders. This also allows to include these files in your versioning system.

How EB deploys new servers, depends on how you have configured it to deploy the application. You can find more information [in the EB development guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html).

Comment: I understood the concept of these files & everything is good; let me give you an example to be more clear, now I have a file called `nginx.conf` in `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` that contains  Nginx config so my question is: Does EB change Nginx config each time I deploy each version to EB?

Comment: I think so yes, but you can easily test this yourself by making a change, updating the application version and check the config with the new application version.